# Is AMP possible with WordPress website built with Timber (Twig)

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, amp-html, timber

I tried different approaches( Wordpress Plugins) to make a WordPress site AMP compatible which is built on Timber(Twig). I did try "AMP by AMP Project Contributors" + "AMP for WP by Ahmed Kaludi, Mohammed Kaludi" but both of them didn't come up with the expected output.

"AMP by AMP Project Contributors" won't be picking the WP post images, Menus, etc. 
"AMP for WP by Ahmed Kaludi, Mohammed Kaludi" gives lot of options like their layouts for AMP Pages but we might need to keep the look and feel in an identical way.

Does it needs to develop from scratch to make this AMP-compatible or is there other workarounds we can easily implement?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://ampify.io

Answer (score 0):

> AMP Pages but we might need to keep the look and feel in an identical way

That is really hard to achieve. The complete AMP Project is based upon rules wich regulates the output in the frontend of a website to achive the boost of performance. Your complete Backend setup (Timber(Twig)) doesn't have a direct touchpoint to your problem.

I would recommend this two options:

1. Choose a AMP ready theme wich is close to your current one
2. Develop a Theme from scratch / edit the theme as a childtheme in order to achieve an identical design (both of your plugins might will help you - not together for sure)